# SPI ioctl hangs when length is 256

Tags: c, embedded-linux

Not sure if it's a C question or something with the driver.

I'm having issues using the ioctl for SPI transfers.
I'm on a yocto linux device using the spidev driver.

I'm only having issues if the buffer length is 255, 256, or 257 bytes. The program hangs and cannot be killed, even with a 'kill -9' command. Any other length works fine and the transfer is successful.

This is the call, pretty straightforward.

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr;
tr.tx_buf = (uint64)WriteBuffer;
tr.rx_buf = (uint64)readBuffer;
tr.len = Count;
tr.delay_usecs = 0;
tr.speed_hz = 1000000;
tr.bits_per_word = 8;

ioctl( _fileDescriptor, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE( 1 ), &tr )
```

I can't understand why the length field would cause it to hang but any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Consider adding `memset(&tr, 0, sizeof tr);` before writing the values.

Comment: `tr.tx_buf = (uint64)WriteBuffer;` This looks like an assignment to a (char) pointer. Why via a cast to an integer? Extra question: what are WriteBuffer and ReadBuffer?

Comment: It might be that your SPI host controller is using DMA with special alignment  requirement. Or even you might found a bug there.